# Adding options with map to Select generates error payload exceeded 1MB

Tags: javascript, node.js, select, html-select

I have error from `[bugsnag] Error: payload exceeded 1MB`

This error appears when i click on Select element to select some option.

At first i though that this errors is comming from Redux where i take values from options.

But after a litle invistigation, i found out that error is comming from select.

When i try add options with map

```
  const arr = [
     {id: '1', name: 'one'}, 
     {id: '2', name: 'two'}, 
     {id: '3', name: 'three'}, 
     {id: '4', name: 'four'} 
  ]


      <Select
      >
        {
          arr.map( element => <Option key={element.id} value={element.name}/> )
        }
      </Select>
```

Maybe anyone knows how to do it in correct way ?

Comment: In the browser, right click and choose Inspect and then go to the network tab. Then click the dropdown/select (to reproduce the bug) and have a look at the network activity. "Payload exceeds 1MB" sounds to me like a large network request failing for some reason... but it's hard to say since haven't provided much context.

Comment: @RockySims Yes i thought it's comming from large request in Redux.
But i stopped to use redux at all, at the moment.
And just trying to print out hardcoded data this way.
And still recieve this error when i click on Select